# What would the broadcast action to receive address from maps app in android

Tags: java, android

What would be the **Broadcast Action** to receive the address of a location from gmaps app in android. For example the gmaps can share the location address using messaging app, whatsapp etc. These show up in the **share using** screen from gmaps. How can I make my app show up like that in the "share using"  option in maps app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register for `android.intent.ACTION_SEND`.

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html